# How to eliminate stop words only using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am able to get the code to spit out a word and its frequency. But, I want to eliminate stop words only using scikit-learn. nltk does not work in my workplace. Does anyone have any advice on how to eliminate the stop words?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['my big dog', 'my lazy cat'])
df
         0
0   my big dog
1  my lazy cat

value_list = [row[0] for row in df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)]
value_list
['my big dog', 'my lazy cat']

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()
x_train = cv.fit_transform(value_list)
x_train
<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
x_train.toarray()
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
cv.vocabulary_
{'my': 4, 'big': 0, 'dog': 2, 'lazy': 3, 'cat': 1}

x_train_sum = x_train.sum(axis=0)
x_train_sum
matrix([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2]], dtype=int64)
for word, col in cv.vocabulary_.items():
print('word:{:10s} | count:{:2d}'.format(word, x_train_sum[0, col]))
word:my         | count: 2
word:big        | count: 1
word:dog        | count: 1
word:lazy       | count: 1
word:cat        | count: 1

with open('my-file.csv', 'w') as f:
     for word, col in cv.vocabulary_.items():
         f.write('{};{}\n'.format(word, x_train_sum[0, col]))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can initialize your CountVectorizer with self-defined stop_words. For example, add `my` and `big` to stop_words will leave only `cat` `dog` `lazy` in vocabulary:

```
stop_words=['my', 'big']
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)
x_train = cv.fit_transform(value_list)
x_train.toarray()
array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)

cv.vocabulary_
{'cat': 0, 'dog': 1, 'lazy': 2}
```

Comment: But if I didn’t want to manually get rid of them? I want the code to parse out stop words on its own.

Comment: Maybe you can use, 
    stop_words= 'english'
a built-in stop word list for English is used,
or you may find a stop words list elsewhere and input it in,  
or you can generate a stop words list by yourself. In this way, you need to count the word frequency, then pick out the most frequent ones.